# Add method result to window/frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My program works currently. It displays the result of the event.WQLookup() method call to the console just fine.

I am trying to modify the code to display the event.WQLookup() result in a text area in the window frame. I have tried several ideas from adding JTextArea and JLabel, though as soon as I try to add or append them in the ActionPerformed method it errors due to either void not allowed or the variable appears to be out of scope.

The code displayed here shows my append attempt using JTextArea.

I feel that it is mostly likely a simple fix though my research leads me back to suggestions I have already tried. I am obviously new to Java so any and all guidance is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WQQuery extends JFrame implements WindowListener,ActionListener,Runnable {

JButton button1;
JLabel InterFaceLabel;
JLabel ErrorCodeLabel;
JTextField InterFaceField;
JTextField ErrorCodeField;
JTextArea SQLLabel;
String InterFace = "";
String ErrorCode = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WQQuery window = new WQQuery("WQ Lookup");
    window.setSize(400,500);
    window.setVisible(true);
    JTextArea SQLLabel = new JTextArea(2,20);
    window.getContentPane().add(SQLLabel);
}

@SuppressWarnings({"OverridableMethodCallInConstructor", "LeakingThisInConstructor"})
public WQQuery(String name) throws IOException {
    super(name);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addWindowListener(this);

    InterFaceLabel = new JLabel("Interface: ");
    add(InterFaceLabel);

    InterFaceField = new JTextField(10);
    InterFaceField.addActionListener(this);
    add(InterFaceField);

    ErrorCodeLabel = new JLabel("Error Code:");
    add(ErrorCodeLabel);

    ErrorCodeField = new JTextField(10);
    ErrorCodeField.addActionListener(this);
    add(ErrorCodeField);

    button1 = new JButton("Search");
    add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    InterFace = InterFaceField.getText();
    ErrorCode = ErrorCodeField.getText();
    WQSQL event = new WQSQL(InterFace, ErrorCode);
    try {
        SQLLabel.append(event.WQLookup());
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WQQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

@Override
public void run() {
      } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you've taken the result from your `WQSQL` query and tried updating the UI (maybe just using a `JTextArea`)?

Comment: I have added the append code and the JTextArea code that I used.

Comment: 1) Add components before `pack()`, then only `setVisible(true)` after that. Update the text content or state of the component after user or GUI action. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: *"Could you.."* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tips on how to use Stack Overflow. You were sort of on the right path with your first suggestion. I would suggest adding such answers as an actual answer post in the future so it can be fleshed out there as a viable answer, and appropriately scored, rather than left in comments. With your rep score and history, you are obviously well aware of that process and I wonder what the benefit of differing here is? Maybe, you can edify me as to what that benefit might be?

Comment: It's quite common I'll toss suspicions into comments, when I don't have enough information to be sure. The thing is, I won't look that closely at the code in questions until there is a [mcve] posted, and that is tricky to do when the code accesses a DB. On the other hand, if it turns out my suspicion is correct, I'll take the information from the comment and turn it into an answer. I'll loo to do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the "void type not allowed" message. It means that I am calling a method that is a void type and expecting it to return data.

Simple fix is to change the method WQLookup, which is called with the append code, from a void to a String type. A simple fix for a simple mistake.

The second fix was to move the JTextArea SQLLabel initialization to WQQuery class:

```
public class WQQuery extends JFrame implements WindowListener,ActionListener,Runnable {

    JButton button1;
    JLabel InterFaceLabel;
    JLabel ErrorCodeLabel;
    JTextField InterFaceField;
    JTextField ErrorCodeField;
    JTextArea SQLLabel = new JTextArea(2,20);
    String InterFace = "";
    String ErrorCode = "";
```

In addition the add of the actual JTextArea needed to be moved with the rest of the components:

```
public WQQuery(String name) throws IOException {
    super(name);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addWindowListener(this);

    InterFaceLabel = new JLabel("Interface: ");
    add(InterFaceLabel);

    InterFaceField = new JTextField(10);
    InterFaceField.addActionListener(this);
    add(InterFaceField);

    ErrorCodeLabel = new JLabel("Error Code:");
    add(ErrorCodeLabel);

    ErrorCodeField = new JTextField(10);
    ErrorCodeField.addActionListener(this);
    add(ErrorCodeField);

    button1 = new JButton("Search");
    add(button1);
    add(SQLLabel);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
```

On a side note I also added a line to clear the text area in the actionPerfomed method:

```
SQLLabel.setText(null);
```

Program compiled and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried several ideas from adding JTextArea and JLabel, though as soon as I try to add or append them in the ActionPerformed method ..

While it is *possible* to add components to an existing GUI dynamically, it is a little tricky to make it work correctly, and I feel there are better strategies. One of those strategies is:

- Add components before `pack()`
- `setVisible(true)` after all components are added.
- **Update the *text content or state* of the component after user or GUI action.**